# How to get rid of the double beep when loading Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, iso

I installed Kali Linux as a Live USB following the instructions on the official website:

```
sudo dd if=kali-linux-2022.4-live-amd64.iso of=/dev/sda bs=4M conv=fsync status=progress
```

When I boot into Kali Linux I hear two beeps. This is very loud and I find it unacceptable. At first I thought it was some problem with my hardware or drivers. However, it turns out that Kali Linux behaves this way by default (it is nightmare).

Then I tried to find out how to get rid of this behavior. I found information to comment out two lines in `/boot/grub/config.cfg` on the Live USB:

```
insmod play
play 960 440 1 0 0 4 440 1
```

However, it turned out that on my main system the Live USB is mounted with read-only permissions, and there is no way to change this.

Then I decided to try to change these lines in the original ISO image. To do that I mounted the file:

```
sudo mount -o loop kali-linux-2022.4-live-amd64.iso /media/iso
```

Copied the entire contents of the ISO image into the directory:

```
cp -r /media/iso/ kali-linux
```

Then I modified the file /boot/grub/config.cfg; updated the checksum files just in case; rebuilt the ISO image:

```
mkisofs -o kali-linux.iso kali-linux/
```

Next, I downloaded the ISO image to the USB flash drive again:

```
sudo dd if=kali-linux.iso of=/dev/sda bs=4M conv=fsync status=progress
```

However, after such manipulations it is impossible to boot from the flash drive: it is simply not in the list of available to boot.

Apparently, I somehow assembled the ISO image wrong. Please tell me how to build it correctly. And in general, maybe you know a much simpler way to get rid of that sound?

P.S. I work under Linux and want to know how to solve my problem on Linux, all from the CLI. So I say in advance - do not suggest using Rufus :)

Comment: "on my main system the Live USB is mounted with read-only permissions, and there is no way to change this" - `mount -o remount,rw`?

Comment: @Panki not if it's booted from a ram image of an iso

Comment: Possible duplicate [Make iso as "bootable (dos/MBR sector)" in mkisofs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/708672/100397)

Comment: @Panki, it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty method… just `hexedit` it! Comment it out without changing any byte offsets, i.e. make it the same length, for example by changing `play 960` to `#### 960`. The only problem with this approach is that checksums / signatures won't match anymore, if anyone is checking them.

Original:

```
~ # mount -o loop kali-linux-2022.4-live-amd64.iso{,.loop}
~ # grep -C 1 play kali-linux-2022.4-live-amd64.iso.loop/boot/grub/config.cfg
# Comment these two lines out to disable the beep on boot
insmod play
play 960 440 1 0 4 440 1
```

hexedit or sed or awk or whatever:

```
~ # sed -e 's/insmod play/#nsmod play/' \
        -e 's/play 960/#lay 960/' \
    < kali-linux-2022.4-live-amd64.iso \
    > kali-nobeep-linux-2022.4-live-amd64.iso
```

Patched:

```
~ # mount -o loop kali-nobeep-linux-2022.4-live-amd64.iso{,.loop}
~ # grep -C 1 play kali-nobeep-linux-2022.4-live-amd64.iso.loop/boot/grub/config.cfg
# Comment these two lines out to disable the beep on boot
#nsmod play
#lay 960 440 1 0 4 440 1
```

Verify that this is the only change:

```
~ # cmp -l kali-linux-2022.4-live-amd64.iso kali-nobeep-linux-2022.4-live-amd64.iso
5153011 151  43
5153023 160  43
```

It's not a very nice method to patch files like this, but sometimes it'll do.